# Laravel 5.6 Undefined variable: aseguradora

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un controlador donde hice una función para que, de acuerdo a una aseguradora seleccionada, me devuelva los vehículos que no están registrados en esa aseguradora. Al momento de ejecutar la función me manda el error:

> "Undefined variable: aseguradora"

Esta es la función:

```
public function mostrarVehNAs(Request $request){
    $aseguradora = $request -> input ('sel_as');
    $datos = \DB::table ('crlo_vehiculos') 
            ->whereNotIn('id_vehiculo', function($query) {
                $as = $aseguradora; //Aqui marca el error
                    $query->select('id_vehiculo')
                    ->from('crlo_veh_asegurados')
                    ->where('id_aseguradora', '=', $as);
            })->get();
    return $datos;
}
```

Y aqui esta [el controlador completo](http://jsfiddle.net/qj9uw31p/).

Intente hacer la siguiente consulta y esta si devuelve resultados:

```
public function mostrarVehNAs(Request $request){
    $datos = \DB::table ('crlo_vehiculos') 
            ->whereNotIn('id_vehiculo', function($query) {
                    $query->select('id_vehiculo')
                    ->from('crlo_veh_asegurados')
                    ->where('id_aseguradora', 1);
            })->get();
    return $datos;
}
```

De antemano gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: prueba pasándola como parámetro de la function `function($query,$aseguradora)`

Comment: Me arroja este error: **Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\crlo_ControllerVehAsegurados::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected**

Comment: y si pruebas con use `function($query) use ($aseguradora)`

Comment: Funciono a la perfeccion, muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

debes usar el use, si no llega la variable

```
public function mostrarVehNAs(Request $request){
$aseguradora = $request -> input ('sel_as');
$datos = \DB::table ('crlo_vehiculos') 
        ->whereNotIn('id_vehiculo', function($query) use ($aseguradora) {
            $as = $aseguradora; //Aqui marca el error
                $query->select('id_vehiculo')
                ->from('crlo_veh_asegurados')
                ->where('id_aseguradora', '=', $as);
        })->get();
return $datos;
```